# jmeter - Unable to capture the random number generated using math.floor

Tags: jmeter

[image: Request from results tree][image: Beanshell post processor][image: Http sampler request][image: Response where rndnum defined]I could see a random number calculated in the response as below
var rndnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);

The subsequent request is expecting this rndnum to be passed. Unable to see the number generated in the response. If I just pass some random number, the response time is high and incorrect.

Any help?

Comment: I can share the response and request where rdnnum generated and expected.

Comment: Response:
var rndnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 11);
                    
url = '../WebPages/EE/OnlineForm.aspx?ContentType=EE@@EEOnlineForm@@formcontent&ReqType=MemberEEForm&CampaignInstanceID=' + campInstanceid + "&rndnum=" + rndnum + "&FormOutput=Online" + requestedsection;

Request:
ContentType EE@@MemberEEOnlineForm@@formcontent 
ReqType MemberEEForm 
CampaignInstanceID 346 
rndnum 8

Comment: Yes, it's javascript and rndnum is http sampler parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You need to store the result in a JMeter variable using:

> vars.put(‘rndnum’, ‘’+rndnum);

Comment: I used your statement beanshell post processor and it's just returned string value "void" and didn't return the rndnum.

Comment: it doesn’t return the value, it stores it in ${rndnum} which is what I understood from your question

Comment: It stored void string value in ${rndnum} and not stored the actual random number generated in the response.

Comment: check logs you most probably have an error in jmeter.log. Point to it

Comment: I don't see any error in the log and could get the same string value "void" in debug post processor too.

Comment: I am afraid I don't clearly understand your question, maybe you should clarify it by explaining what you want to have and what your currently have and show some screenshots

Comment: Have shared the screens with my question.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. `rndnum` variable **is present** in the response. If so, you should be able to extract it using [Regular Expression Extractor](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter).
2. `rndum` variable **is NOT present** in the response. If so you are free to generate a random number between 0 and 10 via JMeter's [__Random() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) like:

   ```
   ${__Random(0,10,)}
   ```

Be aware that according to JMeter Documentation:

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, **JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages**. Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does

so my expectation is that you should go for point 2.

Comment: If I pass a random number generated using __Random() function, the sample time is too high and incorrect. The sample time is accurate(when compared with F12 latency) in the proxy recording results as its passing the passing the rndnum generated in the response.